# Type.GetTypeCode on Universal Windows Platform

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, uwp

How can I get the [`TypeCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode(v=vs.110).aspx) Enum from a `Type` object on UWP?

[`Type.GetTypeCode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettypecode(v=vs.110).aspx) is currently not supported for UWP.

Comment: I hear you; it is a pain; for some of my multi-target stuff, I've essentially ended up duplicating the concept of `TypeCode` locally and re-implementing it - it then works everywhere, even where `TypeCode` doesn't exist

Comment: Oh, so it actually isn't supported? The `TypeCode` Enum itself does exist, so I figured there would also be a way to get it on UWP, probably hidden in some reflection extension method I couldn't find

Comment: Can you try to add a reference to proper `System.Runtime.dll` 4.1.0 from NuGet? Then you should be able to see this method. I checked .NET Core source code and it is there.

Comment: Alright, this seems to be a Unity issue. Visual Studio has no problem building the solution, but it spews out compiler errors when exporting with Unity's "Universal 10 SDK" setting. Thanks for the help

Comment: Forgot to mention, if you are really porting YamlDotNet, consider making it a  .NET Core library against a certain .NET Platform Standard, then all platforms can consume the resulting NuGet package. I already have mine migrated.

Comment: Well, it would be rather tricky on Unity, as Unity is the only left-behind platform in .NET/Mono ecosystem. It uses a very old version of Mono, which would probably fail to support even .NET Platform Standard 1.0.

Comment: I am rather new to Unity and C#/.NET, so I don't exactly know what you mean. I didn't install YamlDotNet through NuGet, but through Unity's Asset Store. I got it working now though, by rolling my own `IsAssignableFrom` chain to be able to export from Unity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you happen to have an instance of an object, you can use `Convert.GetTypeCode(obj)`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.gettypecode(v=vs.110).aspx